# How to compare EF core code-first database with existing Azure Sql Server database

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework, sqlcompare

we have multi-tenants databases and we have special `stored procedure` to compare the structure of the tenents after each release. Now, we are moving to `Azure SQL Server` and the `stored procedure` is not working anymore because we use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, ... like this:

```
SET @SelectTables = 'SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.''+ TABLE_NAME FROM '+ @SourceDatabase + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' '
INSERT INTO #SourceTableNames EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SelectTables

SET @SelectTables = 'SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.''+ TABLE_NAME FROM '+ @DestinationDatabase +'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' '
INSERT INTO #DestinationTableNames EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SelectTables
```

and we got an error:

```
    Reference to database and/or server name in 'Database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

In an emergency situation we use `Visual Studio SQL Compare` or `RedGate Compare` tools but it would be better to compare the structure of the existing database with a newly created database based on EF Core after each release. Would you please guide me about that? I do not like to compare the tenant one by one after each release with the mentioned tools.

Comment: You can re-write your procedure to use sys.tables and sys.columns as these are the preferred method for SQL Server.

Comment: But it returns just tables of one database, not from the other database.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I stopped looking when I saw "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" as that is a deprecated feature.  You will need to adapt your system to be run from a central point and compared that way.  It's difficult to setup cross-database queries with Azure SQL.  Easier to have something like Powershell loop over each database, grab the details, dump to a common database and then read/compare from there.  Or you could start using database projects for your SQL Source control and then let it handle detecting/generating the differences.